# Honeypot not working on PHP form

Tags: php, forms, spam, honeypot

I'm trying to use this gem to create a honeypot field, but I'm not sure how to implement it. How does the form know which field to make the honeypot and where do I specify the label?

So it should work like this:

1. User gets to landing page
2. User sees registration form consisting of:

   1. email address input box
   2. honeypot field which is hidden
3. If a bot registers it will fill in the honeypot, so when the invitation is being created I can automatically accept the ones that don't fill out the honeypot and the ones that do will be rejected.

Here is the code I've used for the form

**index.php**

```
        <div id="customer_lay">
            <h1>Customer Service</h1><br/><br/>
            <div id="enewsletter">
                <ul>    
                    <p>Subscribe to eNewsletter</p>
                    <li><a href="javascript: alert("eNewsletter informs about newest products, product updates and technical information.If you like to be informed about current issues please leave us your email address.Each newsletter contains a link to unsubscribe from the mailing list');"><img src="images/index/bt_guide.gif" width="65" height="30" /></a></li>
                </ul>
                <form name="enewsform" id="enewsform" action="enewsletter_ins.php" onsubmit="return sendData(this)">
                <dl>
                    <dt>E-mail</dt>
                    <dd><input name="email" type="text" size="20" maxlength="40" id="form_style01"/></dd>
                    <dt>Name</dt>
                    <dd><input name="name" type="text" size="20" maxlength="40" id="form_style01"/></dd>
                    <p><input type=image src="images/index/bt_Subscribe.gif" width="65" height="47" /></a></p>
                    <span style="margin-left:40px" id="errormsg"><a href="#"></a></span>
                </dl>   
                </form>
            </div>


----

<?
include_once $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/popup_list.php";
include_once $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/include/_footer.php";
?>

<script src="javascript/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#enewsform').validate({
            errorLabelContainer: "#errormsg",
            rules: {
                email: {required: true, email:true},
                name: {required: true, minlength:2, maxlength:12},
            },
            messages: {
                email: {required:" * Required ", email:" * Not Valid Email"},
                name:  {required:" * Required ", minlength: " * at least 2 characters", maxlength: " * up to 12 chars"}
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**enewsletter_ins.php**

```
<?
include_once $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/include/initiate.php";



if(trim($name)=="" or trim($email)==""){
    alert("send errer!!");
}



$form_title=$email."님의 Subscribe to eNewsletter 신청";
$user_name=$name;
$user_email=$email;
$body="
date : ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."
<hr>
Name : $name
<hr>
E-Mail : $email
";

$sql = "
        insert into prd_form_data set
            form_type = '3',
            form_title = '".$form_title."',
            user_name = '".$user_name."',
            user_email = '".$user_email."',
            user_content = '".$body."',
            insdt = now()
";
mysql_query($sql) or error(mysql_error());

//메일발송
$comments = $body;

$mailTo     =   ADMIN_MAIL; // 받는 메일 주소;
$mailFrom   =   "test@example.com"; //  

$mailSubject = "Subscribe to eNewsletter";
$mailContent = $comments;

$mailHeader = "From: $mailFrom\r\n";
$mailHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$mailHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

$mailResult = mail ($mailTo, $mailSubject, $mailContent, $mailHeader,'-f'.$mailFrom);
?>

<form method="post" action="/" name="frm">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    alert("ok!!");
    document.frm.submit();
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would put a field in your form with type="hidden" and then check to see if there is a value in that field when you submit.